# Calendar translation/internationalization

Tags: calendar, internationalization, translation

Can anyone tell me why on earth is the calendar internationalized/translated into the the "Location's" target language while the system is English and no other languages were installed? E.g.: Cluj-Napoca → Romanian (the names of the months and starting letters of the days)

Is there any solution to keep the location and change the names and letters to the system language? I would really prefer the English version.

Comment: What calendar? And what do you mean by location here? The location of an event in the calendar? The location where your computer physically is?

Comment: The location is only important to set your computer in the right timezone, it has nothing to do with the system-language. The Ubuntu installer tries to guess your language (and keyboard layout) according to your location but you can still set them up to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that calendar applications typically fetch the weekday and month names from the selected [Regional Formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html) locale. One way is to change that setting to one of the English options, but it will change various kinds of format settings all over the system.

Another way is to edit your `~/.profile` file and add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

Even if that too will change the date and time format all over the place, it will keep things like number and currency formats in accordance with your setting in *Language Support*.